# How to make a word from Byte []?

Tags: c

I am new to programming world, I want to convert two bytes into a word.

So basically, I have a Byte array where index 0 is `Buffer[0]=08` and index 1 is `Buffer[1]=06`
I want to create a word from these two bytes

where word `ETHType to be 0x0806`

Comment: Do you know how to do it mathematically?

Comment: would be good if can also provide me the way to do it simple C

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use bitwise operators and bit shifting.

```
uint16_t result = ((uint16_t)Buffer[0] << 8) | Buffer[1];
```

This does the following:

- The value of `Buffer[0]` is shifted 8 bits to the left.  That gives you 0x0800
- A bitwise OR is performed between the prior value and the value of `Buffer[1]`.  This sets the low order 8 bits to `Buffer[1]`, giving you 0x0806

Comment: Wow that is exactly what I needed, thanks I will accept it as my answer, could you also explain it a little bit, just for the non technical persons like me, would love to know what really is happening here

Comment: @OmChoudhary Added some more detail.

Comment: To anyone who might use this code in future: it is important to ensure that all numbers involved in bitwise calculations are unsigned. In the context of this answer, `Buffer` must be a pointer to `unsigned char`, `uint8_t` or some other unsigned type. Otherwise, `Buffer[1]` will be promoted to `int`, filling most significant bits with garbage.

Comment: The left operand of `<<` should be cast to an unsigned type of at least 16 bits before `<< 8`. On machines where `int` is 16 bits, this shift could overflow `int`, resulting in behavior not defined by the C standard.

Comment: @anatolyg Yes, that needs to be accounted for.  Added a cast to the destination type to prevent those issues.

Answer (score 2):

```
word ETHType = 0;
ETHType = (Buffer[0] << 8) | Buffer[1];
```

edit: You should probably add a mask to each operation to make sure there is no bit overlap, and you can do it safely in one line.

```
word ETHType = (unsigned short)(((unsigned char)(Buffer[0] & 0xFF) << 8) | (unsigned char)(Buffer[1] & 0xFF)) & 0xFFFF;
```

Comment: The left operand of `<<` should be cast to an unsigned type of at least 16 bits before `<< 8`. On machines where `int` is 16 bits, this shift could overflow `int`, resulting in behavior not defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a macro I use for this very thing:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define MAKE16(a8, b8) ((uint16_t)(((uint8_t)(((uint32_t)(a8)) & 0xff)) | ((uint16_t)((uint8_t)(((uint32_t)(b8)) & 0xff))) << 8))
```