# Convert Hex bytes to an ASCII string (Codesys)?

Tags: hex, ascii, codesys

I have 4 bytes:

```
Byte_0=0x31
Byte_1=0x32
Byte_2=0x33
Byte_3=0x34
```

And I would like to get a word_1=0x1234, where 1 is the conversion from hex to ASCII. Any ideas about how to get this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. A `BYTE` is 8 bits and a `WORD` is 16 bits. You can combine two bytes into a word by [bit shifting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520169/how-to-make-a-word-from-byte) using [`SHL`](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/2528934539.html?id=8659902399805093076).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to previous suggestion there is another way to convert string to integer and bytes to string.

```
PROGRAM PLC_PRG
    VAR
        arBt : ARRAY[1..4] OF BYTE := [16#31, 16#32, 16#33, 16#34];
        pstrString : POINTER TO STRING(4);
        iInt : INT;
    END_VAR

    pstrString := ADR(arBt); // now pstrString^ is equal to "1234"
    iInt := STRING_TO_INT(pstrString^); // now iInt = 1234 number
END_PROGRAM
```

If you have Codesys 2.3 then delete `[` brackets in `[16#31, 16#32, 16#33, 16#34]`.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an internal function available to translate an ASCII text digit to its numerical value, but you can easily write one yourself:

```
FUNCTION Ascii_To_Byte : WORD

VAR_INPUT ascii : BYTE

IF ascii>=16#30 AND ascii<=16#39 THEN  // range 0-9
  Ascii_To_Byte := ascii - 16#30;
ELSIF ascii>=16#41 AND ascii<=16#46 THEN  // range A-F
  Ascii_To_Byte := ascii - 16#41 + 16#0A;
ELSE
  Ascii_To_Byte := -1  // error condition, invalid input
```

Then it's just a matter of converting the values and bit shifting:

```
word_1 := SHL(Ascii_To_Byte(Byte_0), 12) + SHL(Ascii_To_Byte(Byte_1), 8) + SHL(Ascii_To_Byte(Byte_2), 4) + Ascii_To_Byte(Byte_3)
```

(Code written in TwinCAT, may be slightly different in Codesys.)